# TCPDF how do i keep a copy of the generated .pdf on my server?

Tags: tcpdf

I am building a simple ticket system which creates a dynamic generate .pdf file and emails it as an attachment. 
Right now i am testing with static pdf file, but i notice tcpdf deletes the file on the server.

1/ HOw can i prevent this and keep a copy on the server?

Regards

Comment: $pdf->Output('FileName.pdf', 'D'); It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, use 'F' as the second argument in the TCPDF output function and specify a path to store the file on server

```
$this->pdf->Output('/path/example_001.pdf', 'F');
```